# How to refresh ProgressBar accurately

Tags: c#

I wrote a short method that uses a for loop 2 times:

```
progressBar1.Minimum = 1;
progressBar1.Maximum = 1000000;
progressBar1.Step = 1;

for (int idx = 1; idx < 1000000; idx++)
{    
    progressBar1.PerformStep();
}

Thread.Sleep(2000);
progressBar1.Invalidate();
this.Update();

progressBar1.Value = 1;
for (int idx = 1; idx < 1000000; idx++)
{
    progressBar1.PerformStep();
}
```

My question is this: on the 1st pass, when the value gets to 1000000 the actual colored bar only
displays about 50-75% across, but never 100% across, even though the value has reached the maximum.

This is unique to using the progressbar multiple times in one method.

How can I get the actual colored bar to get to the very end?

(Apparently its a buffering thing?)

Comment: Actually, IMO, if you want to update the ProgressBar accurately, you should perform your work in another thread (for instance with a BackgroundWorker), as to not obstruct the GUI thread.

Comment: The green progressbar in Vista and up is animated and has smooth progress, no matter what the step size.  Smooth progress is the problem here, it makes the visible bar lag behind the Value.  You make it a *lot* worse by blocking the UI thread, not permitting this animation to take place at all.  A workaround is to *decrement* the Value, the bar instantly catches up.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that you're blocking your UI thread. Don't do that. Perform all the long-running tasks in a background thread (e.g. a `BackgroundWorker`) and marshal back to the UI thread to update the progress bar (`BackgroundWorker` makes this pretty trivial)... then all should be well.

Comment: And the worse solution, even if it may be simpler, is to use `DoEvents` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.doevents.aspx) after *each* call to `PerformStep`.

Comment: @ken2k: I know, that's why I wrote the "worse solution" ;-) It still works though

Answer (score 2):

As Jon said, doing work on your UI thread interferes with IU updates, making the interface unresponsive. That's why you do the work on a background thread.

Use a BackgroundWorker and update your progress bar on the worker's ProgressChanged event:

```
    {
        progressBar1.Value = 1;
        progressBar1.Minimum = 1;
        progressBar1.Maximum = 100;
        progressBar1.Step = 1;

        var bgw = new BackgroundWorker();
        bgw.ProgressChanged += bgw_ProgressChanged;
        bgw.DoWork += bgw_DoWork;
        bgw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        bgw.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    void bgw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        // do your long running operation here
        for (int idx = 1; idx <= 100; idx++)
            // when using PerformStep() the percentProgress arg is redundant
            ((BackgroundWorker)sender).ReportProgress(0); 
    }

    void bgw_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.PerformStep();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks to all of you! Great input, and I learned to make use of the BackgroundWorker! Again, thanks so very much!

Answer (score -1):

```
progressBar.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate ()
{
    this.progressBar.Value = (int)((100 * indexOFfreq) / countFReq);
    PB_persent.Text = progressBar.Value.ToString() + "%";
});
Application.DoEvents();
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.