# How can i display in a progressBar the green color progress and also percentages inside?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have this code:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
     this.toolStripProgressBar2.Value = Math.Min(this.toolStripProgressBar2.Maximum, e.ProgressPercentage);
     this.toolStripProgressBar2.ProgressBar.CreateGraphics().DrawString(e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + "%", new Font("Arial", (float)8.25, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new PointF(this.toolStripProgressBar2.Width / 2 - 10, this.toolStripProgressBar2.Height / 2 - 7));
}
```

If i'm using only the second line it will show percentages but without the green color progress.
If i'm using the first line too the percentages will be deleted each time the green color will progress.

And if i'm using only the second line the percentages looks like they paint over and over on them self:

[image: Percentages only]

If i'm using only the first line i will see only the green bar progress fine but without percentages.

This is what i tried now:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    using (Graphics gr = this.toolStripProgressBar2.ProgressBar.CreateGraphics())
    {
        gr.DrawString(e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + "%",
            SystemFonts.DefaultFont,
            Brushes.Black,
            new PointF(this.toolStripProgressBar2.ProgressBar.Width / 2 - (gr.MeasureString(e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + "%",
                SystemFonts.DefaultFont).Width / 2.0F),
            this.toolStripProgressBar2.ProgressBar.Height / 2 - (gr.MeasureString(e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + "%",
                SystemFonts.DefaultFont).Height / 2.0F)));
    }
}
```

And still the percentages in the progressBar is painting over and over on it self.

I'm using `toolStripProgressBar2` that contain `progressBar`

Comment: That's very very buggy code. You ought to dispose the `Graphics` instances which you have created yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```
gr.DrawString(percent.ToString() + "%",SystemFonts.DefaultFont,Brushes.Black,...
```

Please check link below. You need to use the overload of DrawString for adding brush

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/94631-add-the-percent-into-a-progress-bar-updated/

Comment: Updated my question with the code i tried used the exmaple in the link here. But still the percentages get paint over and over. Strange.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds one UI thread is blocking the other . Also i suggest you check [Progressbar Perform Ste](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8761060/how-to-refresh-progressbar-accurately) . And on [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.progressbar.step(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
progressBar.PerformStep();
```

It forces the progressbar to update the progress each instance

```
toolStripProgressBar2.Value = Math.Min(this.toolStripProgressBar2.Maximum,e.ProgressPercentage);


toolStripProgressBar2.ProgressBar.CreateGraphics().DrawString(e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + "%", new Font("Arial", (float)8.25, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new PointF(this.toolStripProgressBar2.Width / 2 - 10, this.toolStripProgressBar2.Height / 2 - 7));
toolStripProgressBar2.PerformStep();
```